# Kafka: Republish 24 hours of messages at the time they were initially published

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, scheduled-tasks, replay

I have logged 24 hours of messages published on kafka (from midnight to midnight). 
There are about 1.2 million messages.

Now, for testing purpose, I would like to use these logs to "replay" the messages (i.e., starting at midnight, read the logs and republish each message at the time it was sent initially).

Is there a tool or a library (ideally in Java or Scala) that does this?

Answer (score 2):

You can write something like using the [offsetsForTimes](https://kafka.apache.org/0102/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/Consumer.html#offsetsForTimes(java.util.Map)) that is available since Kafka 0.10, rewinding to given offset, and then consuming & producing record until next midnight